# regular expression repeating

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to add 'ig' in the middle of each syllable in a word. For example, super (su and per) would become sigupiger (sigu and piger) Here is my code so far:

```
function iggify(text) {
    var iggEdText = text.split(/((a|e(?!$)|i(?!ng$)|o|u|y){1,3}|le$|ing$)/ig).join("ig");
    document.getElementById('resultField').innerHTML = iggEdText;
}
```

[**Demo codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWLgaY)

My regular expression repeats twice after joining. e.g. words becomes wigoigoigrds, instead of simply wigords.
How can I make it only repeat once?

Comment: What are you trying to make this function do? Add "ig" after the first consonant of each word within the input string?

Comment: I'm trying to add 'ig' after each syllable in a word.

Comment: Does [`var iggEdText = text.replace(/(?:a|e(?!$)|i(?!ng$)|o|u|y){1,3}|le$|ing$/ig, "ig$&");`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPJKGZ) solve the issue?

Comment: There are a lot of cases for syllables not being considered in your logic.

Comment: Definitely, `w` is not a syllable.

Comment: Voting to close as *unclear what you're asking*. You say that you want to add 'ig' after every syllable, but then you say that "word" should map to "wigord". These are totally different, mutually exclusive requirements.

Comment: @stribizhev: That totally works. Thank you! Can you explain the changes you added?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting an joining, you just need to append `ig` to the vowels that can be easily achieved with `.replace()`:

```
text.replace(/(?:a|e(?!$)|i(?!ng$)|o|u|y){1,3}|le$|ing$/ig, "ig$&");
//            ^^^ - Non-capturing group                        ^^ - The whole matched text
```

I removed the outer capturing group and changed the second one to non-capturing. Since we replace with the whole match, I use the `$&` back-reference in the replacement part (i.e. I restore the matched text during replacement and add `ig` before it).

See the whole snippet below:

```js
function iggify(text) {
    var iggEdText = text.replace(/(?:a|e(?!$)|i(?!ng$)|o|u|y){1,3}|le$|ing$/ig, "ig$&");
    document.getElementById('resultField').innerHTML = iggEdText;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Convert words to wig-ords!
</h1>
<div>
  <input id="inputBox" placeholder="Type words to iggify here">
</div>
<div>
  <button id="searchButton" onclick='iggify(document.getElementById("inputBox").value)'>Iggify!</button>
  <span id="resultField"></span>


</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think I will remove the CSS, it looks cleaner. The codepen is available at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPJKGZ.